# How to extract Hours and Minuets from a column of timestamp like 0 Days 09:30:15 from column in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract hour, minutes and seconds from below column data frame.

```
0 days 09:30:00
0 days 10:00:00
0 days 10:30:00
0 days 11:00:00
0 days 11:30:00
0 days 12:00:00
0 days 12:30:00
0 days 01:00:00
0 days 01:30:00
```

From this to below format i want to remove this "0 days" from the data frame column

09:30:00
10:00:00
10:30:00
11:00:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
12:30:00
01:00:00
01:30:00

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `.split()` method and pass in a space, it will return a list of all the words in the string. i.e: `['0', 'days', '09:30:00']`. Then, you just have to return the third entry, assuming that everything follows this format.

```
def foo(string): 
    return string.split(' ')[2]
```

Comment: I want to extract only time 9:30:00 from the timedelta 0 days 9:30:00 and this is for entire column. how can I do this please help.

Comment: yes this is how you would do this. Loop through all of the deltas, and then  yo u should be left with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using series.apply() it will look like this

```py
df['newcolumn'] = df['originalcolumn'].apply(lambda x: x[-8:])
```

Comment: I want to extract only time 9:30:00 from the timedelta 0 days 9:30:00 and this is for entire column. how can I do this please help.